# C# checking dynamic values against null

Tags: c#, exception, dynamic

I have a method that has a dynamic parameter and returns a dynamic result.  I would like to be able to pass null, int, string, etc into my method.  However I get "NotSupportedException" in all situations.

```
MyMethod(null); // Causes problems (Should resolve to ref type?)
MyMethod(0); // Causes problems (Should resolve to int type)

public dynamic MyMethod(dynamic b)
{
  if (value != null) {...}// Throws NotSupportedExpception
  if (value != 0) {...} // Throws NotSupportedExpception
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use dynamic?

Comment: What is "value", and why is "b" not used? This code is very confusing.

Comment: Your method seems to work fine for me (after I renamed `b` to `value`). What is the call stack of the exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029699/c-how-to-perform-a-null-check-on-a-dynamic-object

Comment: Svick is right; this code is fine. Post a small *complete* program that *actually demonstrates the problem*. Making it difficult for us to help you diagnose your problem does no one any good.

Comment: @EricLippert, can you please regard to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234300/linq-to-objects-when-object-is-null-vs-linq-to-sql

Comment: The problem is recently in VS2010 I enabled breaking for all exceptions (Under Debug->Exceptions). The exception that is firing is "System.NotSupportedException" under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". If I continue after this exception or turn it off the code runs correctly. Are not all exceptions bad and should be addressed? Does everyone else turn on exception breaking as I have described?

Comment: why wouldn't you want to use dynamic?

Comment: As a reference to future fellow googlers - I've encountered a similar problem on Mono v 3.2.0 (not a problem on >=3.4.1). It thrown ArgumentNullException on `dynamic a = 5; if(a==null)...`.

Answer (score 5):

it is just working

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyMethod(null);
        MyMethod(0);

    }        
    public static dynamic MyMethod(dynamic value)
    {
        if (value != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Value is not null.");
        if (value != 0)
            Console.WriteLine("Value is not 0.");

        return value;
    }
```

Output

```
Value is not 0.
Value is not null.
```

Comment: The problem is recently in VS2010 I enabled breaking for all exceptions (Under Debug->Exceptions).  The exception that is firing is "System.NotSupportedException" under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".  If I continue after this exception or turn it off the code runs correctly.  Are not all exceptions bad and should be addressed?  Does everyone else turn on exception breaking as I have described?