# How to check if a dynamic object is null

Tags: c#, dynamic, null, tostring

I recently saw the following code, which puzzled me.

```
dynamic resultObj = SomeClass.run(arg);
if (resultObj == null || resultObj.ToString() == null)
{
    /* Error handling */
}
```

Assuming `SomeClass` is your typical class (which does not override `ToString()`), is there a reason why the second part of the conditional would be necessary? Also, are there other potential issues with this code as it is?

Comment: What does `run` return?  If it could possibly return a class that overrides `ToString` in a way that could return null then yes, the second check is necessary if you use the result of `ToString` in your `if` block.  All `dynamic` means is "I don't know the type until runtime".

Comment: If it doesn't override `ToString`, then it's calling `object.ToString()` which returns [the fully qualified name of the type of the Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) - so yes - the `.ToString() == null` check is not required.

Comment: Seems like poor design, to allow random classes to instantiate with random returns.

Answer (score 12):

A dynamic can be checked for null directly, but some circumstances can cause false answers.  In order to check a dynamic for null, you should cast it as an object.  For example,

```
dynamic post = SomeMethod();
if (post.modified == null){
//could return errors.
}
```

in order to check this property for null, you should do something like this:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(post.Modified));
```

similarly, to check a dynamic for null, you should do something like this:

```
if ((object)post != null)
```

References:

https://ericlippert.com/2018/11/19/a-dynamic-definite-assignment-puzzle-part-2/

https://forums.asp.net/t/1592751.aspx?How+to+check+for+null+empty+strings+on+dynamic+objects+

So, by checking a resultObj.ToString() == null I believe this may convert the dynamic to an object and therefore enable for true null checking.

Comment: custom operators may cause null checking on a dynamic object to return different logic than expected.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029699/c-how-to-perform-a-null-check-on-a-dynamic-object.  You can get around this by casting to an object, I believe, feel free to downvote me and provide the reasons why I'm wrong.